# Is there a description of the ring of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}$ as an abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Regarding $\mathbb{Q}$ as a field, there is only the trivial automorphism. What happens if we only consider $(\mathbb{Q},+,0)$ as an abelian group? Is there a description or way to compute the ring of endomorphisms $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{Q},+,0)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. $\def\Q{\mathbb{Q}}$ $\def\End{\text{End}}$Suppose that $f\in\End(\Q)$. Then, you may note that since $f(n)=nf(1)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ we clearly have

$$qf\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=f(p)=pf(1)$$

so that

$$f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=\frac{p}{q}f(1)$$

Thus, we have a bijection $\End(\Q)\to\Q:f\mapsto f(1)$. Since, if $f(x)=ax$ and $g(x)=bx$ for $a,b\in\Q$ we have that

$$f(g(x))=f(bx)=bf(x)=baf(x)$$

and

$$(f+g)(x)=ax+bx=(a+b)(x).$$

Thus, we see that $\End(\Q)\to\Q$ is actually a ring isomorphism.

This more generally shows that if $R$ is an integral domain then, as rings, $\End_R(\text{Frac}(R))\cong \text{Frac}(R)$.

Comment: That's even more general - if $R$ is a domain and $(R)$ is its field of fractions, than for any $(R)$-modules $V, W$ we have that $Hom _{(R)}(V, W) \simeq Hom _{R}(V, W)$. :)

Comment: @PiotrPstragowski The $R$-module isomorphism, yes. But not the ring structure :)